# Running Google Apps code within an external python script

Tags: python, google-apps-script

Is it possible to mix languages in a single script for Google apps? I’ve written and deploy an apps script from an external python editor, which connects to an apps console through the web API.

Part of the code I’ve taken from a another open source app that was written in Google’s javascript-like apps language. It works well and i dont need to modify it much.

The rest of the script calls other Google products and is coded in python.

Would it be possible to in some way copy the Google-apps-javascript code into my external python script?

I want all of the code in one place, rather than have part of it in python on an external editor and part of it in the apps console.

Hope this question was clear. Thank you!

Comment: You should be able to manually convert the code to python. The services typically used in Google Apps Script often have a corresponding REST API so you can substitute those in python with the appropriate google api module.

Comment: yeah, but its a lot of work to convert the entire program to python. Im hoping there is a more efficient method of mixing the languages